# Timescale associated with screened Coulomb potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential

The force on a particle moving under the influence of Harmonic oscillator potential is :
$$\textbf{F}=-m\omega^2 \textbf{r}.$$
By solving the equation of motion one can easily infer that the time scale associated with the potential is :
$$\tau_h \sim \frac{1}{\omega}.$$
Similarly, let us consider the screened Coulomb interaction potential,
$$V(r)=\frac{A}{r}\exp{(-r/\lambda)},$$
where, $A$ is a constant ( $A=\frac{q^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$). It is difficult to explicitly solve the equation of motion governed by this potential. My question is : how can I figure out the timescale associated with this potential ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timescale of the motion resulting from a given force law is generally an ill-defined quantity. The harmonic oscillator is a peculiar system because all the possible motions are periodic with the same frequency. However, this behavior is not typical of dynamical systems. Generally, if a periodic motion is present, its frequency depends on the initial conditions. Moreover, aperiodic motions are also possible and, if Fourier analyzed, they correspond to the presence of more than one timescale.

Comment: Which quantity to Fourier analyze to find the timescales ?

Comment: @bubucodex For a generic motion, I would expect a wide range of frequencies, and, worse, such a range is also not unique but depends on the initial conditions.  Said in another way, usually, there is no single timescale.

Comment: @bubucodex, the quantity to analyze should be directly the position or velocity as a function of time.

Comment: So ,  can I expect to get multiple peaks in the Fourier transformed position or velocity time series ?

Comment: @bubucodex in general, I would expect a continuum without well-definite peaks.

Comment: I ran a simulation with just two interacting particles with periodic boundary conditions. The power spectrum turns out to be continuum.